# Range address, where do I find the sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I work on a  UDF and the user inputs a  range, say "sheet1!A1:C8".

In the VBA I write the following:

```
Function RelativeSearch(Search, rng As Range, Row, Column)
    MsgBox rng.Address
```

Here the msgbox only gives me A1:C8. How can I get the "Sheet1"?

I have tried to make rng as string but that does not work as I have to use rng.find later in the code.

Anyone know of a way to get the sheet from the range?

Comment: The question is ... why do you need to know what sheet is being referred to?  I can't think of any real reason why a well-written UDF would need to know that information - you should be able to just use `rng` as a `Range` object without worrying about which worksheet, or even workbook, that it exists on.

Comment: @YowE3K I need it for knowing what sheet to look at. The UDF asks for a search needle, a search range and column and row offset. I find needle in range and manipulate the range with offset row an column. So basically it's a "vlookup" that is a bit more flexible since it can go up/down/left and right in the sheet from where it matches. Offsetting the address is not a problem but since the sheet is not carried on the address that meant it matched on say sheet5 and returned value from sheet1.

Comment: I haven't had time to look at the answers here yet, will do that tomorrow but they both look correct. Thank you both.

Comment: So you will be doing something like `Set rng2 = rng.Find(Search)`, followed by something like `RelativeSearch = rng2.Offset(Row, Column)`? I still don't understand why you need to know the sheet name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Range` object has a `Worksheet` property, so:

`rng.Worksheet.Name` will do what you want.

In addition the `Address` property has an `External` argument, so:

`rng.Address(External:=True)` yields the entire range address, e.g.,  `[Book1]Sheet1!$D$28`.

Answer (score 1):

To get a reference to the `Sheet`, use `rng.Parent`.
In your specific case, you are looking for `rng.Parent.Name`.

So you could do

```
MsgBox rng.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Address
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer to the question you asked, but I suspect it might help you avoid having to ask the question.*

If you are trying to find, within `rng`, the value passed as `Search`, and then return a value derived by some offset by `Row` and `Column`, there is no need to know what worksheet `rng` is on:

Excel formula (perhaps in cell Sheet4!D6):

```
=RelativeSearch("b",Sheet1!A1:A6,3,2)
```

Code which will search the range A1:A6 in Sheet1 for the value "b" and then return the value from the cell that is 3 rows below and 2 columns to the right:

```
Function RelativeSearch(Search, rng As Range, Row, Column)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = rng.Find(What:=Search, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If r Is Nothing Then
        RelativeSearch = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Else
        RelativeSearch = r.Offset(Row, Column).Value
    End If
End Function
```

(If you want it to be consistent with `VLOOKUP`'s syntax, you will need to use `r.Offset(Row - 1, Column - 1)` rather than `r.Offset(Row, Column)`.)